# Mulesoft XSLT Streaming Large xml files

Tags: xslt, mule

I am currently using Mulesoft 3.6 CE. I am have a large xml file, which I would like to split it into small xml elements and push to jms queue. I am trying to explore XSLT options to achieve this using mule's out of box streaming functionality without writing code.

For example I have a incoming file as

```
<books> 
   <book>
     <isbn>1</isbn>
     <title>Book 1</isbn>
   </book>
   <book>
     <isbn>2</isbn>
     <title>Book 2</isbn>
   </book>
....
</books>
```

and I want to write each  element to JMS queue the following snippet

```
<book>
    <isbn>1</isbn>
    <title>Book 1</isbn>
</book>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

Since Mule does support XSLT 2.0/3.0, you could probably try something like this, assuming ISBNs are unique

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/books/book">
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="output_{isbn}.xml">
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I don't think you'll be able to capture the output of that without custom code or a separate port, but I'm not 100% sure of how Mule would handle this either.

To be honest, I would question whether you'll get good performance out of this - at the very least, I don't think it would perform as well as a forward-only reader (XMLStreamReader in Java) to just keep lopping off those `<book>` nodes and passing them to your JMS queue.